# How did positioning the menu item in toolbar at leftMost corner after toolbar navigationButton

Tags: material-design, android-toolbar, menuitem, android-theme, uitoolbar

Currently i am creating toolbar in my fragment i have to implement searchView on this toolbar and i put toolbarNavigation button also.i set searchview.OnActionExpanded() on it so its behavier was good but** its just little space between my navigation button and Expanded searchview i want to take it out** . Can anyone Help me to solve this?

And also i have implemented searchview item in the menu Resource directory.its single item in there.

I have try to rearrange with its style resource directory.i pick parent as widget Appcompat.SearchView and i set items like android:paddingLeft as -10dp like that.its move pretty good as given attributes but the toolbar dont allows to set content nearer to the predefined NavigationToolbar button.it has limitation to its boundry.i dont how to cancel out?